# Hybris call path of media

Tags: media, sap-commerce-cloud, impex

I want to call path of picture with impex script.
I've this path C:%PATH%\hybris\bin\custom\yb2bacceleratorstorefront\web\webroot_ui\responsive\common\images\img_KE185.
How can i call it in @media[translator=de.hybris.platform.impex.jalo.media.MediaDataTranslator]?

Thank you for helping

Answer (score 1):

You can give path similar like below:

```
INSERT_UPDATE Media;@media[translator=de.hybris.platform.impex.jalo.media.MediaDataTranslator];...
; jar:com.yourdomain.YourClass&/www/responsive/common/images/img_KE185 ;...
```

Comment: What do you mean by .YourClass&?

Comment: @AyaI You just need to give the path of your picture, so that Hybris can pick it up and convert it to media.

Comment: @TrishulSinghChoudhary, I put it like that jar:de.hybris.yb2bacceleratorstorefront.web.webroot&/www/responsive/common/images/img_KE185 but doesn't work. The complete path of my picture is C:\HybrisInstallllllll\hybris\bin\custom\yb2bacceleratorstorefront\web\webroot\_ui\responsive\common\images\img_KE185. Can i find a help?

Comment: I can't know your image location without your custom extension yb2bacceleratorstorefront package name. YourClass mean, your package.

Comment: @mkysoft I try to do it like this: $commonResourcePath=jar:de.hybris.platform.yb2bacceleratorstorefront.controllers.pages.MockedPLPPageController&/yb2bacceleratorstorefront/responsive/common                    $commonResourcePath/images/img_KE_185/SS01S.png     But don't work